# Relation of specific angular momentum $h$ with velocity and impact parameter for massive particle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion, scattering

I am computing the path of an incoming massive (!!) particle with speed $v$ far from the black hole in the schwarzchild metric. To determine its path, i need to input the specific angular momentum parameter $h$, defined as $h = r^2 \dot{\phi}$. What is the function $h = h(b,v)$ that i am looking for? (where $b$ is the impact parameter)

Please ask further questions if i am not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular momentum is $\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{p}$. Thus by definition, the impact parameter is a ratio of the magnitudes of angular momentum to linear momentum.
$$b = \frac{L}{p}$$
From the energy-momentum 4-vector (assuming units with $c = 1$),
$$E^2 - p^2= m^2$$
$$p = \sqrt{E^2-m^2}$$
$$b = \frac{L}{\sqrt{E^2-m^2}}=\frac{L/m}{\sqrt{(E/m)^2-1}}$$
For a particle with initial velocity, $v_f$, starting far from a Schwarzschild black hole
$$\gamma_f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_f^2}}$$
$$E^2 = m^2 +p^2=m^2(1+\gamma_f^2 v_f^2)$$
$$\frac{E^2}{m^2} = 1+\frac{v_f^2}{1-v_f^2}=\frac{1}{1-v_f^2}$$
$$\frac{E}{m} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v_f^2}}=\gamma_f$$
$$\frac{L}{m} = b \sqrt{\gamma_f^2-1}$$
Both $E/m$ and $L/m$, as measured by the far-away observer, are conserved on the particle's trajectory.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for, i cannot thank you enough!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user11339690, You are welcome! A good elementary reference for simple black hole calculations, orbits, etc., is Taylor and Wheeler, Exploring Black Holes. An [updated](http://www.eftaylor.com/exploringblackholes/) pdf version is avaliable.

Comment: do u also have the relation of h with b for the case of a photon?

Comment: @user11339690, The impact parameter is still $b=L/p$, but for light you must use the momentum of a photon (hint, what happens as $m \rightarrow 0$?). The impact parameter for massive particles and light is discussed in Chapter 11 of the reference I gave in a previous comment. It was discussed in Chapter 5 in the original book.